# Assign custom field price as product price to specific user role in WooCommerce more than one

Tags: php, actionscript, addition

`your text`Assign custom field price as product price to specific user role in WooCommerce (more than one)
i used above code i found at stack overflow

I created a new role called "_2". (from plug in)  The role works fine

I also created a custom price field called "Wholesaler price2". It also works fine

how can i make more // woocommerce_product_options_pricing  id, label to work ?

how can i make more woocommerce_product_options_pricing  id, label to work ?
My functions.php code i used so far is below:`your text`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 10, 0 );
   /* Add custom wholesaler price field to general page */
    function action_woocommerce_product_options_pricing() { 
        'woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'wholesaler_price2', 
        'class' => 'short wc_input_price', 
        'label' => __( 'Χονδρική 2', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
    ) );
}

    

// Save Fields
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    if( isset($_POST['wholesaler_price2']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'wholesaler_price2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'wholesaler_price2'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );


/* Custom prices by user role */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price_assign', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price_assign', 10, 2); 
// For product variations (optional)

function custom_price_assign( $price, $product ) {
    // Check if the user has a role of wholesaler
    if ( current_user_can('_2') && $wholesaler_price2 = $product->get_meta('wholesaler_price2') ){
        return $wholesaler_price2;
    }
    return $price;
}
```